# Re-initialize variables in Tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, neural-network, tensorflow

I am using a Tensorflow `tf.Saver` to load a pre-trained model and I want to re-train a few of its layers by erasing (re-initializing to random) their appropriate weights and biases, then training those layers and saving the trained model. I can not find a method that re-initializes the variables. I tried `tf.initialize_variables(fine_tune_vars)` but it did not work (I'd assume because the variables are already initialized), I have also seen that you can pass variables to the `tf.Saver` so that you partially load the model, however that is half of what I want to achieve (because when I save the trained model, I want it to save all variables not only the ones I loaded).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you pass the result of `tf.initialize_variables(fine_tune_vars)` to `sess.run()`?

Comment: That was the exact problem!

Comment: maybe `initialize_variables` should be called `initialize_variables_op`

Comment: I think that that would clear up the ambiguity!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`initialize_all_variables` should work to re-initialize previously initialized var.

Just did this sanity check in 0.10

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
a = tf.Variable(tf.ones_initializer(()))
init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
modify_op = a.assign(5.0)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(init_op)
print(a.eval())
sess.run(modify_op)
print(a.eval())
sess.run(init_op)
print(a.eval())
```

Result

```
1.0
5.0
1.0
```

Comment: Thank you! as mrry said, my problem was that I did not use sess.run() on it!

Comment: initialize_all_variables is deprecated, You need to use global_variables_initializer instead of.