# Re-initialize variable in TensorFlow to custom value

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to initialize a `w_gate` tensor with a custom `np.array` as in the code below:

```
    w_init = np.ones(shape=(dim, self.config.nmodels)) / self.config.nmodels

    w_gate = tf.Variable(
        name="W",
        initial_value=w_init,
        dtype=tf.float32)
```

Every a certain number of train iterations, I want `w_gate` to be re-initialized again to the `w_init` array. For this, and based on [Re-initialize variables in Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38947754/re-initialize-variables-in-tensorflow), I tried

```
sess.run(tf.variables_initializer([w_gate]))
```

inside my training loop. This line is executed every certain number of iterations. Although, `w_gate` doesn't seem to be re-initialized. What am I missing here?

Comment: It should work. Just be sure that that you are not overwriting `w_gate`. You should use `tf.assign()` or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try this and check ?

```
w_gate_assign = tf.assign(w_gate, w_init)
sess.run(w_gate_assign)
```